# How to make a button call a function that uses the fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm practicing using the fetch API for a project I'm working on and having trouble getting a button to call a function that uses the fetch API to access an external API. Keep getting a 'Type Error: Failed to Fetch' message.

```js
const uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    const initDetails = {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        mode: "cors"
    }
    
    function getData() {
        fetch(uri, initDetails)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                response.status);
                return;
            }
    
            console.log(response.headers.get("Content-Type"));
            return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(myJson => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
        });
    }
    
    window.onload=function() {
        let myButton = document.getElementById("getData");
        myButton.addEventListener('click', getData);
    }
```

```html
<form>
    <button id='getData'>Get Data</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button is inside a form. The default action of buttons inside forms is to submit the form, which reloads the page and aborts the fetch request.

Either `preventDefault()` in the form submit handler, add `type="button"` to the `<button>` element, or (ideally, in this case) remove the `<form>` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one its working for me.**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>

        const uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
        const initDetails = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            mode: "cors"
        }

        function GetData() {

            fetch( uri, initDetails )
                .then( response =>
                {
                    if ( response.status !== 200 )
                    {
                        console.log( 'Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                            response.status );
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log( response.headers.get( "Content-Type" ) );
                    return response.json();
                }
                )
                .then( myJson =>
                {
                    console.log( JSON.stringify( myJson ) );
                } )
                .catch( err =>
                {
                    console.log( 'Fetch Error :-S', err );
                } );
        }
    </script>
        <button id='getData' onclick="GetData()">Get Data</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after adding a **"<form>"** section in an HTML page where I had Ajax calls with `fetch()` from "<button>":

There is a problem when putting a <form> tag and using a `fetch()` with values not coming from the "form" from a "<button>" tag ...

The solution is then to put the button via a tag "**<input type ="button"...>**

```
 <input type="button" id='getData' onclick="GetData()" value="Get Data">
```